# How to plug an HDMI cable into a hotel HDMI port which is accessible but concealed?

Tags: hotels

I have an Amazon Firestick that I like to use sometimes with TV's in hotels. Unfortunately, the TV's are usually mounted on the walls in such a way that the HDMI ports are accessible, but difficult to access and impossible to see (due to the recessed area in which the TV is mounted).

Last night I spent about a half hour trying to plug my HDMI cable into a hidden port (yes, I'm stubborn), and finally succeeded.

Has anyone found any way to make this process simpler? I have learned to slide my phone in and take a photo of the ports so that I at least know what they look like. Maybe an HDMI cable with the plug mounted at a 90 degree angle with respect to the cable would help?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Many hotels have media panels with all these connections, not necessarily near the TV itself

Comment: Firesticks sometimes come with short flexible extenders or angled ones.

Comment: If you can find the exact model of the TV, you could try to find a picture of the back side online, or look in the user manual. A problem might be that the type number is usually on the back side too...

Comment: In hotels where the TV has hard-to-get ports, it's more and more common that the TV will accept Chromecasting or AirPlay, which usually (but not always) makes things easier. In some circumstances (but that becomes more rare as the functionality gets integrated into the TVs) there can be an external set-top box, so you could disconnect the cable at that end, though in the case of a Firestick you would need a F/F adapter I believe.

Comment: @littleadv I have never seen this. I am staying in low- and mid-level hotels in Southeast Asia and rarely see high end equipment.

Comment: @badjohn I don't think mine came with one, but I like the idea, I can look for a third party extender like that.

Comment: @berend As I said I was able to get a photo of the panel with jacks, so I knew where to plug it in and in what orientation. It was just really difficult because I was doing it blind.

Comment: @jcaron This particular TV did not seem to have that function, but yes, that's a great solution.

Regarding the external set top box, I haven't seen that. These tv's do usually have cable boxes but I think they're usually connected with coax cables so that doesn't help me.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use your phone's flashlight and/or camera to identify where the jack is and what it's orientation is, then you do like everyone who has a wall-mounted TV does: Orient the plug in the right direction, then stick your hand back there and grope in the dark until you get it connected. If there's enough room, hold the flashlight in the other hand and smoosh your head against the wall to gain vision with one eye. I've done this many times with wall mounted TVs. "This is the way."

Comment: @KeithBennett You are a whole ocean away from me so I cannot lend you any of the spare ones that I have.